# Javascript - Remover o evento clique de um botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boas pessoal,

Tenho o seguinte problema: como mostra a imagem seguinte, tenho um conjunto de botões para avançar e recuar a sequência do processo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, exatamente nesta parte, preciso que ao clicar no `botão next` a página espera `x segundos` antes de avançar. 
Tenho o seguinte código para parar a propagação do evento de clique do botão e para o fazer avançar novamente:

```
$('#btnnexttop, #btnnextdown').on('click', function (event) {
//só funciona quando o tab4 estver active 
var tab4 = $('#tab4').attr('class');
var svgShow = $('#capaemboss_laser').attr('class');
var embossChosen = $('#dlemboss2_laser').val();
//Imagens SVG criar com o btnnext em vez do preview 

if (svgShow == "row" && tab4 == "tab-pane active" && embossChosen != 'EMBOSS-D005') {

    var btnclicked = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(" teste" + btnclicked);
    event.stopPropagation();

    //obter o valor mais baixo do tamanho selecionado 
    var sizeVal = $("#dlformat2").val();
    var withouI = sizeVal.replace(/\i/g, '');
    var splitInt = withouI.split("x");
    var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, splitInt);
    var pxValue = (minValue / 2) * 37.795276; // 37.795276 pixeis correspondem a 1cm! verificar!!


    //novo texto para as imagens
    var newText = $('#txt_emboss_laser').val();
    var newText2 = $('#txt_emboss2_laser').val();
    var newText3 = $('#txt_emboss3_laser').val();
    var newText4 = $('#txt_emboss4_laser').val();

    var svg_blob = "";

    //obter id da imagem selecionada 
    var imgSelected = $('#dlemboss2_laser').val();
    // por height igual ao pxValue

    setTimeout(function () {

        if (btnclicked == "btnnexttop") {
            $('#btnnexttop').off('click').trigger('click');
        } else if (btnclicked == "btnnextdown") {
            $('#btnnextdown').off('click').trigger('click');

        }
    }, 1000);
}});
```

A minha ideia foi usar o `event.stopPropagation();` para parar o evento de clique no botão e o `setTimeout` para fazer o `trigger` de um novo clique.

Problema: o primeiro clique em cada botão `next` (representados com os `ids: btnnextdown e btnnexttop`) funciona na perfeição, contudo, se eu voltar atrás e fizer novo clique deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Se você tiver interesse e puder refatorar o seu código, eu indico dar uma pesquisada em "máquinas de estado finito" para resolver esse tipo de problema. Uma busca rápida da pra encontrar [uma pronta que funciona com o jQuery](https://github.com/lucaong/jquery-machine).